# Method I am using for table insert/update and save in ruby is way too slow. How can I speed this up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Ruby noob alert: It took 8 hrs to insert 300,000 records in ruby. It was devastatingly slow. How can I improve the below code? Below, for every fetch of row from the connection object I am doing an active record save. I have concluded that's whats causing majority of the slowness. How can I change my code to make the inserts blazing fast?

```
class SiteSection < ActiveRecord::Base

  SiteSection.establish_connection(
        :adapter  => 'postgresql',
        :host     => 'hoster-of-hosts.com',
        :database => 'super-inven',
        :username => 'user',
        :password => 'pass'
                      )
  self.table_name = 'master.target_tbl'  # << insert into this table
end

conn.query("select * from source_tbl") do |row|
  siteData = SiteSection.find_or_initialize_by_head_date_and_center_id_and_site_url(row[:date_c], row[:com_id], row[:site_link])

  siteData[:head_date]      = row[:date_c]
  siteData[:center_id]     = row[:com_id]
  siteData[:site_url]          = row[:site_link]
  siteData[:people_cnt]      = row[:persons]
  siteData[:ips]     = row[:ip_adds]

  siteData.save  # For every record from source_tbl query, save it in master.target_tbl.
i = i+1
puts "finished: #{i}" if i % 10000 == 0
end
conn.close
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered backing up the table and moving it to the other database?  Then the inserts can be done in bulk...

Comment: How, what do you mean in bulk? the daily update is 300,000 records

Comment: If this is a daily task, you should output the data to a text file and use a bulk insert.  [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html), and [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm#i1009127) all have specific ways of doing this.

Comment: And if you need to merge some records but add others then do a bulk load into a temporary table, insert the missing records with a single SQL statement, and update the mergeable records with another SQL statement. Pumping 300k rows through ActiveRecord isn't a terribly productive use of your time, SQL will do the job much faster.